# Trouble understanding the physics of a voltaic cell

Tags: electrochemistry

I recently watched a few videos on the electrochemistry of voltaic cells on youtube and then after watching a video of a physical demonstration of a voltaic cell in action, I realized the videos were insufficient in describing all the processes involved in a voltaic cell.  Specifically, I noticed in the demonstration video that no current was being registered on the ammeter until the salt-bridge was connected.  This led me to reformulate a model of how the voltaic cell works.

My current model of how I understand a voltaic cell:

> 1. A solid mass of zinc is placed into a glass filled with a liquid solution of zinc(2+) ions and sulfate SO4(2-) ions.  Additionally, a solid mass of copper is placed into a separate glass filled with a liquid solution of copper(2+) ions and sulfate SO4(2-) ions.
> 2. Since there is physical connection between the two masses, no electrons can pass between them.
> 3. Before connecting a wire, the mobile electrons are moving randomly within the masses.  After connecting a wire solely to the zinc mass, the electrons will begin to move into the wire and a potential gradient will form along the length of the wire and begin causing electrons to drift down the wire.
> 4. The transfer of electrons from the zinc mass to the wire will result in the creation of zinc ions.  The zinc ions will detach from the main zinc mass and move into the zinc sulfate solution increasing the positive charge of the liquid.
> 5. After connecting the other end of the wire to the copper, the gradient will begin moving the electrons at the end of the wire into the copper.  Here, the electrons bond to the copper(2+) ions in the solution and the ions attach themselves to the zinc mass.  This results in an increase in negativity of the copper sulfate solution.
> 6. If there is no salt bridge, then the zinc sulfate solution will become positive and attract the electrons of the zinc mass which eliminates the electric potential gradient within the wire which halts the net flow of electrons from the zinc mass through the wire into the copper mass.
> 7. By adding a salt bridge, the net positive charge in the zinc sulfate solution becomes reduced due to the inclusion of the negative chlorine ions and the net negative charge in the copper sulfate solution becomes reduced due to the inclusion of positive sodium ions.
> 8. The salt bridge therefore maintains the electrical neutrality of the two solutions which allows the zinc-wire-copper gradient to exist uninterrupted.

My question is:

1. Is this model correct?
2. What exactly is the timescale on this?  If the salt bridge is removed, are the zinc ions pretty rapidly being removed from the zinc mass and overwhelming the zinc sulfate solution with positive charges?  It must be a very quick process and the amount of zinc ions necessary to disturb the neutral net charge of the zinc sulfate solution must be invisible to the eye if this is the case.

Comment: Have you tried other sources than videos?  As this is very frequent topic,explained in textbooks and online resources in many ways and places.

Comment: See also CH SE META post about [policy for "Am I right?" questions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/policy-on-amirite-questions)

Comment: Propagation of electrostatic force due charge disbalance is extremely fast and the force proportionality factor to the net charge is enormous. This is not specific to electrochemistry.

Answer (score 2):

Your model is nearly correct. I would modify it this way.

When a zinc plate is dipped into a $\ce{ZnSO4}$ solution, one or two $\ce{Zn}$ atoms are giving their electrons into the metal, and these atoms become $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ ions which pass into solution. But this phenomena lasts less than one nanosecond. It stops because the $\ce{ZnSO4}$ solution becomes then positively charged, and this positive charge prevents new positive $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ ions from entering the solution.

A similar phenomena occurs on the copper plate when dipped in a $\ce{CuSO4}$ solution. As soon as the copper plate is dipped into such a solution, one or two $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ ions are taking electrons from the copper plate, to become $\ce{Cu}$ atoms. But this phenomena lasts less than one nanosecond. It stops because the corresponding $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ ions have not been modified (discharged) and remain in solution: As a consequence the solution becomes negatively charged. Ions from such a negative solution cannot pick up new electrons from the copper plate.

So if now the two electrodes are connected with a wire connecting both plates, nothing new will happen.

But, if now a $\ce{NaCl}$ salt bridge is installed connecting both solutions, this creates a voltaic cell which will work for two reasons : First the positively charged solution around the zinc plate attracts the negative ions from the bridge and around the copper plate. Second, the negatively charged solution around the copper plate attacks the positive ions from the bridge and from around the zinc solution. The electric neutrality of all parts of the voltaic cell is maintained. So it works.